# need to print labels from a ecommerce website

Tags: .net, php, mysql, e-commerce

Im a wiz with php but i have a challenging client- who wants sandwich labels printed automatically as they are ordered from their website.

what is the best solution for this- the e-commerce website is a php/mysql website i can do a call to some sort of service running but i have no idea how to print the info? what hardware is required.. and where to go for info. I'm sure it can be in some sort of .net app as the printer will connected to a windows machine.

Comment: "labels"...very generic requirement.  Nutritional info?  Price?  Barcode?  Need to provide details to get a good answer here.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a programed task in windows every minute or every 30 sec that execute a php (php c:/dir/myphpcron.php) wich check out if there is a new order an then generate a pdf and then execute with exec() this:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Foxit

Comment: am planning on using the zebra printers

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean with that. i thinks the printer you use dont affect the solution. If you install the drivers correctly printing a pdf with an HP, epson or zebra involves the same steps.